# editing javascript nav buttons in a slider, previous and next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am currently styling the nav buttons of hero slider using css, below is my code, however I want to achieve the buttons like on the slider on www.bbc.co.uk. With the expanding div and the text appearing. Could sombeody show me how please?

This is the css for the buttons I would like to edit

```
.hero-carousel-nav li {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 48px;
            right: 48px;
            list-style: none;
            }

        .hero-carousel-nav li.prev {
            left: 48px;
            right: auto;
            }

        .hero-carousel-nav li a {
            background: #FFF;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            padding: 5px 20px;  
            -moz-border-radius: 20px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            behavior: url(/assets/PIE.htc);
            }

        .hero-carousel-nav li a:hover { 
            background: #06C;
            }
```

and this is my javascript which includes the coding for the previous and next nav buttons that I would like to edit.

```
jQuery.fn.heroCarousel = function(options){

options = jQuery.extend({
    animationSpeed: 1000,
    navigation: true,
    easing: '',
    timeout: 5000,
    pause: true,
    pauseOnNavHover: true,
    prevText: 'Previous',
    nextText: 'Next',
    css3pieFix: false,
    currentClass: 'current',
    onLoad: function(){},
    onStart: function(){},
    onComplete: function(){}
}, options);

if(jQuery.browser.msie && parseFloat(jQuery.browser.version) < 7){
    options.animationSpeed = 0;
}

return this.each(function() {
    var carousel = jQuery(this),
    elements = carousel.children();
    currentItem = 1;
    childWidth = elements.width();
    childHeight = elements.height();

    if(elements.length > 2){

        elements.each(function(i){
            if(options.itemClass){
                jQuery(this).addClass(options.itemClass);
            }
        });

        elements.filter(':first').addClass(options.currentClass).before(elements.filter(':last'));

        var carouselWidth = Math.round(childWidth * carousel.children().length),
        carouselMarginLeft = '-'+ Math.round(childWidth + Math.round(childWidth / 2) ) +'px'

        carousel.addClass('hero-carousel-container').css({
            'position': 'relative',
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'left': '50%',
            'top': 0,
            'margin-left': carouselMarginLeft,
            'height': childHeight,
            'width': carouselWidth
        });

        carousel.before('<ul class="hero-carousel-nav"><li class="prev"><a href="#">'+options.prevText+'</a></li><li class="next"><a href="#">'+options.nextText+'</a></li></ul>');

        var carouselNav = carousel.prev('.hero-carousel-nav'),
        timeoutInterval;

        if(options.timeout > 0){
            var paused = false;
            if(options.pause){
                carousel.hover(function(){
                    paused = true;
                },function(){
                    paused = false;
                });
            }
            if(options.pauseOnNavHover){
                carouselNav.hover(function(){
                    paused = true;
                },function(){
                    paused = false;
                });
            }
            function autoSlide(){
                if(!paused){
                    carouselNav.find('.next a').trigger('click');
                }
            }
            timeoutInterval = window.setInterval(autoSlide, options.timeout);
        }

        carouselNav.find('a').data('disabled', false).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var navItem = jQuery(this),
            isPrevious = navItem.parent().hasClass('prev'),
            elements = carousel.children();
            if(navItem.data('disabled') === false){
                options.onStart(carousel, carouselNav, elements.eq(currentItem), options);
                if(isPrevious){
                    animateItem(elements.filter(':last'), 'previous');
                }else{
                    animateItem(elements.filter(':first'), 'next');
                }
                navItem.data('disabled', true);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    navItem.data('disabled', false);
                }, options.animationSpeed+200);
                if(options.timeout > 0){
                    window.clearInterval(timeoutInterval);
                    timeoutInterval = window.setInterval(autoSlide, options.timeout);
                }
            }

        });

        function animateItem(object,direction){
            var carouselPosLeft = parseFloat(carousel.position().left),
            carouselPrevMarginLeft = parseFloat(carousel.css('margin-left'));

            if(direction === 'previous'){
                object.before( object.clone().addClass('carousel-clone') );
                carousel.prepend( object );
                var marginLeft = Math.round(carouselPrevMarginLeft - childWidth);
                var plusOrMinus = '+=';
            }else{
                object.after( object.clone().addClass('carousel-clone') );
                carousel.append( object );
                var marginLeft = carouselMarginLeft;
                var plusOrMinus = '-=';
            }
            if(options.css3pieFix){
                fixPieClones(jQuery('.carousel-clone'));
            }
            carousel.css({
                'left': carouselPosLeft,
                'width': Math.round(carouselWidth + childWidth),
                'margin-left': marginLeft
            }).animate({'left':plusOrMinus+childWidth}, options.animationSpeed, options.easing, function(){
                carousel.css({
                    'left': '50%',
                    'width': carouselWidth,
                    'margin-left': carouselPrevMarginLeft
                });
                jQuery('.carousel-clone').remove();
                finishCarousel();
            });
        }

        function fixPieClones(clonedObject){
            var itemPieId = clonedObject.attr('_pieId');
            if(itemPieId){
                clonedObject.attr('_pieId', itemPieId+'_cloned');
            }
            clonedObject.find('*[_pieId]').each(function(i, item){
                var descendantPieId = $(item).attr('_pieId');
                $(item).attr('_pieId', descendantPieId+'_cloned');
            });
        }

        function finishCarousel(){
            var elements = carousel.children();
            elements.removeClass(options.currentClass).eq(currentItem).addClass(options.currentClass);
            options.onComplete(carousel, carousel.prev('.hero-carousel-nav'), elements.eq(currentItem), options);
        }

        if(jQuery.browser.msie){
            carouselNav.find('a').attr("hideFocus", "true");
        }

        options.onLoad(carousel, carouselNav, carousel.children().eq(currentItem), options);

    }

});

};
```

Answer (score 0):

BBC website is actually using a custom javascript library called [glow](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/). you might want to look at this:

Alternatively you can also use this [slider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/touchcarousel-wp/#example-2), by checking the source code.